# Telegram API SendVoice method sends voice as file

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to send voice message thorough SendVoice method but it sends the voice as a simple ogg file ( not playable ).

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendVoice?chat_id=x&voice=http://majidamiri.com/up/5.ogg
```

In the [Telegram API SendVoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice) it points that the file should be in .ogg opus format , so I converted a mp3 file to opus ogg by ffmpeg with this code :

`<?php $myConvert = exec('ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mp3 -acodec libopus -b:a 64k -vbr off -compression_level 10 5.ogg'); ?>`

And again like before it sends it as file.

My ogg Link : https://majidamiri.com/up/5.ogg

Can you help me with this issue ?

Thank you all .

Comment: Have you solved this in the end? I tried all sorts of options and I have the same problem.

Comment: @mbrt no unfortunantely i couldn't solve the problem so i gave up on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally made this work, with the help of Telegram support. This is an example with all the flags needed:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -codec:a opus -b:a 128k -vbr off -ar 24000 test.ogg
```

Tested on both Android and Telegram web.

Comment: I have similar problem.
By using your command I get the following error **Unrecognized option 'vbr'**

Comment: Solved, for me the right command is 
**ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -strict -2 -acodec opus -b:a 128k -ar 24000 audio.ogg**

Comment: `-ar 24k` → **Specified sample rate 24000 is not supported**

Comment: If `-ar 24k` or `-ar 24000` are not accepted, go back to `-acodec libopus`. For me, `opus` rejects 24k even in strict -2 mode, but libopus does not.